# android order sqlite table

Tags: android

I have a table called person and it contains two fields, name (TEXT) and age (INT). I want to sort this table alphabetically but I can seem to get the sql statement to work. The statement i am using is:

```
SELECT name FROM person ORDER BY name;
```

I have tried three different coded versions, none of which work.

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM person ORDER BY name;", null);
db.execSQL("SELECT name FROM person ORDER BY name;", null);
db.execSQL("SELECT name FROM person ORDER BY name;");
```

rawQuery does absolutely nothing, no messages are displayed in LogCat. the first execSQL crashes with:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty bindArgs
```

The second execsql crashes with:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error: Queries cannot be performed using execSQL(), use query() instead.
```

I also tried using query() but I couldn't make heads or tails of it. Help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
db.query("person", new String[] {"name"}, null, null, null, null, "name");
```

As per the reference:

```
public Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)
```

If for example you wanted both name and age you would use:

```
db.query("person", new String[] {"name", "age"}, null, null, null, null, "name");
```

If you wanted to select only names with "woody" in them you could use:

```
db.query("person", new String[] {"name"}, "name=?", new String[] { "woody" }, null, null, "name");
```

For processing the results you could do the following:

```
Cursor c = db.query("person", new String[] {"name", "age"}, null, null, null, null, "name");

startManagingCursor(c); 
int nameColumn = c.getColumnIndex("name");
int ageColumn = c.getColumnIndex("age");
c.moveToFirst()) 
do 
{
    // Perform Logic
    Log.i('TEST INFO', 'Name: '.c.getString(nameColumn).' Age: '.c.getInt(ageColumn));
}
while (c.moveToNext());
```

Amendment as per the comment: I am not quite sure why you would want to reorder the data in a database, but the following function should do what you want, you will probably need to modify to suite, it will get all entries (ordered), create a temp table, add the entries, drop the real table and rename the temp table to become the main table again:

*Doing this is very resource hungry - using a properly laid out SQL SELECT statement to order result as they are collected from the DB will use much less.*

```
private void orderDB()
{
    Cursor c = db.query("person", new String[] {"name", "age"}, null, null, null, null, "name");
    startManagingCursor(c); 

    //Create a temp table:
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_person (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "name text not null, " 
        + "age integer);");

    // Get column ID's
    int nameColumn = c.getColumnIndex("name");
    int ageColumn = c.getColumnIndex("age");

    // Iterate through all entries
    c.moveToFirst(); 
    do 
    {
        if (c.getCount() >0)
        {
            ContentValues orderedValues = new ContentValues();
            orderedValues.put("name", c.getString(nameColumn));
            orderedValues.put("age", c.getInt(ageColumn));
            try
            {
                // Insert the entry into a temp table
                db.insert("tmp_person", null, orderedValues);
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                Log.e("TEST INFO", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
    while (c.moveToNext());

    // Drop the current person table:
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person");

    // Rename the temp table to person:
    db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE tmp_person RENAME TO person");  
}
```

Comment: It works sort of. I can print the names in order on screen, but the database is not being updated. When I close and reopen the app, the database is back to what it was originally.

Comment: @Woody the database will not change its structure - the SELECT statement will only request data from the database, and by adding ORDER BY will simply order the results as they are fetched from the database. The database stores a key for each entry as it is added, that keeps the order of the database. Why do you need the database to be reordered? AFAIK the only way would be to perform a select, then empty the table, and then reenter the info in order.

Comment: I just need the database reordered, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

As I read here ([rawQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)), the rawQuery() method does not accept the SQL string with ; terminated.

Your SQL string is not wrong. Just remove the ; and everything will be okay.

But as I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8435932/916490), using db.query() will be more secure for your Database