# rawQuery Vs. database.query

Tags: android, sqlite, comparison

Are their any advantages in using rawQuery over the Query Builder (or vice versa)?

Does the Query Builder, for example, protect again SQL Injection attacks (While not a big a problem as with web sites, SQL Injection + a content provider could be an issue)? or is one faster than the other?

I'm fairly happy with SQL (enough for what I need to do anyway) and so I tend to go for rawQuery (I can read the source code easier), but I'm just wondering if I'm missing something that could be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's definitely preferred to build a query through the methods provided. Not only does it protect you from SQL injections, it also builds the query for you so you can avoid having a whole bunch of string concatenations that will make the query string less readable and more error prone. Performance-wise I don't think it makes much difference.

Comment: By methods provided do you mean Query Builder?

Answer (score 4):

**Readability** is an advantage of the rawQuery. At least for me.

As you know, according to the Pareto principle developer spend 80% of its time reading the code. Therefore the readability is a very strong argument.

Though QueryBuilder also provides the way to use placeholders (protect from SQL injections).

Hope that helps.